# Cannot find module angular 8

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build multiple apps on one project in Angular 8, but I have problem with finding modules. It's seems that path is good, but I'm still getting error 'Cannot find module'. Tried to put full path, but it does not worked either.
My files structure:
[image: My files structure]

My app.module.ts file
[image: My app.module.ts file]

My app.routing.ts file

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home';
import { LoginComponent } from './login';
import { AuthGuard } from './helpers';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },


{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const appRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Is it possible that I have this problem because of multiple apps in one project, or is the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I guess you have to change the path of the routing module to app-routing.module
2. You cannot import the other files without referencing the files direct path. So for HomeComponent it would be `. /home/home.component`
   The same for your interceptors and pipes. You cannot reference the path to its directories, if there is not an index.ts file which exports the directories content

Answer (score 0):

I think you are building multiple project by using ng g application, otherwise you can easily build multiple app in one project by using *ng g [application](https://angular.io/cli/generate#application-command)*

Then you need to export the module in App Module to get that module in child module.

If this is not a solution then plz provide the App routing module

Comment: I was creating new project with command 'ng new [project] --createApplication="false"' and then I was creating 3 seperate applications with 'ng g application [app-name]'. I added app.routing.ts in question

Comment: change
`export const appRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);` in 
 the app routing module to this

`@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }`